# Datatable hace el comando de busqueda pero no muestra el resultado

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

Logre hacer que hiciera el comando de buscar los datos de una tabla, pero no los muestra en la datatable, no se porque. Hace el query, pero no lo muestra.

Ya hice esta pregunta 2 veces, y nadie niquiera le comenta. No se si el tema es muy dificil.

HomeController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}

public function sendData(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'nombre'    =>  'required',
        'precio'     =>  'required',
        'empresa'     =>  'required'
    ]);

    $product = new product([
        'nombre'    =>  $request->get('nombre'),
        'precio'     =>  $request->get('precio'),
        'empresa'     =>  $request->get('empresa')
    ]);
    $product->save();
    return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'Data Added');
}

public function create()
{
    return view('home');
}

public function get_datatable()
{
    return Datatables::eloquent(Product::query())->make(true);
}


}
```

Lo que tengo en web.php

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/home/sendData', 'HomeController@sendData')->name('home/sendData');
Route::get('/home/get_datatable', 'HomeController@get_datatable')->name('home/get_datatable');
Route::get('/home/create', 'HomeController@create');
```

Lo que tengo en home.blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <link  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

            <div class="card-body">
                @if (session('status'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        {{ session('status') }}
                    </div>
                @endif

                Has iniciado sesion
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<br></br>
<center><div class="w3-container">

<div class="w3-bar w3-black">
<button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink w3-red" onclick="opentab(event,'London')">Meter datos</button>
<button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="opentab(event,'Paris')">Ver datos</button>
</div></center>

<div id="London" class="w3-container w3-border city">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-12">
<br />
<center><h3>Meter datos del producto</h3></center>
<br />
<form method="post" action="{{url('home/sendData')}}">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div class="form-group" align="center">
<input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Coloque el nombre del producto" />
</div>
<div class="form-group" align="center">
<input type="number" name="precio" class="form-control" placeholder="Coloque el precio" />
</div>
<div class="form-group" align="center">
<input type="text" name="empresa" class="form-control" placeholder="Coloque el nombre de la empresa" />
</div>
<div class="form-group" align="center">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>

</form>

</div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="Paris" class="w3-container w3-border city" style="display:none">
<center><h2>Productos actuales</h2></center>
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="table" name="table">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th>Id</th>
                 <th>Nombre</th>
                 <th>Precio</th>
                 <th>Empresa</th>
                 <th>Fecha de creacion</th>
                 <th>Fecha de actualizacion</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
        </table>

    <script>
     $(function() {
           $('#table').DataTable({
           processing: true,
           serverSide: true,
           ajax: 'http://localhost/laravel/test/public/home/get_datatable',
           columns: [
            {data: 'id'},
            {data: 'nombre'},
            {data: 'precio'},
            {data: 'empresa'},
            {data: 'created_at'},
            {data: 'updated_at'}
            ]
        });
     });
     </script>
     </div>

<script>
function opentab(evt, cityName) {
var i, x, tablinks;
x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display = "none";
}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-red", "");
}
document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " w3-red";
}
</script>


@endsection
```

Lo que tengo en Product (El modelo)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
 {
 protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'precio', 'empresa'];
 protected $table =  'products';
 protected $primaryKey = 'id';

 }
```

La base de datos

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`producto` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`precio` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`empresa` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Bueno entendi que quieres buscar los datos mediante el datatable?

Comment: Si, quiero que aparezcan en la tabla, el codigo hace el select pero estos no salen.

Comment: y una cosa mas en el ajax usa las ventajas de blade pon ´ "{{ route('home/get_datatable') }}" ´ y en vez del `->make(true)` pon `toJson`

Comment: y otra cosa revisa bien que importes los Javascripts a tu view

Comment: Te refieres a que haga "return Datatables::eloquent(Product::query())->toJson;" y "ajax: '{{ route('home/get_datatable') }}',"

Comment: exactamente eso, por algo le pusiste nombre a tu ruta y es mejor usar ese `name`